# How do I invoke the TypeScript compiler from Jake?

Tags: typescript, jake

If I wanted to invoke jshint from a jake script, I'd do something like this:

```
var jshint = require("jshint").JSHINT;
var pass = jshint(sourceCode, options, globals);
```

I'd like to do something similar with tsc - but does anyone know how to do this? The documentation only tells you how to run this from the command line, and not how to invoke it programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about `jake`. However, the typescript compiler currently has no public interface and hence I believe you cannot call it from `jake`. There is an issue filed for this at [codeplex](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/97). I'd expect it to be fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually exactly what I'm looking for - the ability to export TypeScriptCompiler via NPM module. Jake is the JavaScript build tool that is very much like rake (for Ruby) or psake (for PowerShell).

Comment: It is possible to access compiler with a little bit of hackery. I wrote a require extension to compile .ts file on the fly, it's sources might come handy: https://github.com/eknkc/typescript-require

Comment: Pretty awesome. Installed and tested under MacOS. Works like a charm.